# select the most recent entry

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
LOCATION_ID, PERSON_ID, DATE
3, 65, 2016-06-03
7, 23, 2016-10-28
3, 23, 2016-08-05
5, 65, 2016-07-14
```

I want to build a select query in PL/SQL to select the records with the **most recent** location_id per person_id. For the above sample, the desired result should be:

```
LOCATION_ID, PERSON_ID, DATE
5, 65, 2016-07-14
7, 23, 2016-10-28
```

(DATE expressed as 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check all the answers you received? You marked the most inefficient one as "correct." Wernfried's *second* solution is clearly the best one. It does just one pass over the whole table - there are no joins, so it will be MUCH faster than any join-based solution. The second-best solutions (two passes, but still no joins, so still much faster) are Hawk's solution and Wernfried's *first* solution. If you didn't understand their solutions, you could **ask**.

Comment: I marked "correct" the first answer I read and worked for me. Today, I read all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other proposals are correct but the most compact and fastest solution is most likely when you use [FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE Analytic Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   FIRST_VALUE(LOCATION_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY THE_DATE 
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LOCATION_ID, 
   PERSON_ID, 
   MAX(THE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID) AS LAST_DATE
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Other people prefer

```
SELECT 
   MAX(LOCATION_ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATE) as LOCATION, 
   PERSON_ID, 
   MAX(DATE) as LAST_DATE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY PERSON_ID;
```

which does the same, but I am not so familiar with this clause. See [aggregate_function KEEP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641)

Comment: The preference for the second solution is justified, as it is the correct one. It does not do "the same" as the first one. The first solution uses analytic functions, so the result will have as many rows as the base table (with many duplicates). You need to select from it again (or "group by" or do something) to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @mathguy, I used DISTINCT in first query. Should be correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay attention. It is "correct" in the sense that it will give the right answer, but it may be very inefficient if the table is large. Often when you must use "distinct" (either explicitly or hidden in a GROUP BY etc.) that's a sign that a better solution may exist. In this case it does - it's your second solution.

Comment: Well,the second one also contains GROUP BY, I don't think there is any difference in performance. Maybe on large tables which are partitionized by PERSON_ID the GROUP BY could be more efficient because Oracle can parallize the query.

Comment: In the first solution you "group by" person_id in the partition by clause, and then you are still not done - you still must "distinct" the results. But you are probably right that any difference in performance may be small except for very large tables. I may run some tests and report back - I find that sometimes the results are surprising (perhaps the first solution will turn out to be faster than the second!)

Comment: And, in any case, both solutions will run circles around any "join" based solution (which I pointed out to the OP in a comment to his post).

Comment: The first command returns multiple location_id per person_id. The second works OK.

Comment: Sorry, when you omit the [windowing clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i97640) then Oracle defaults it to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can first extract the most recent event for each person by grouping results by `PERSON_ID` and selecting the `MAX(DATE)`.

Then join the table with itself on those two columns to retrieve the `LOCATION_ID`

```
SELECT
  YOUR_TABLE.LOCATION_ID,
  YOUR_TABLE.PERSON_ID,
  YOUR_TABLE.DATE
FROM
  (SELECT
    PERSON_ID, MAX(DATE) AS max_date
  FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY
    PERSON_ID
  ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
  YOUR_TABLE
ON
  YOUR_TABLE.PERSON_ID = t1.PERSON_ID
  AND
  YOUR_TABLE.DATE = t1.max_date
```

By the way, you should not use reserved words like `DATE` for column names.

Here is fiddle to show it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efdcb/2

Comment: DATE name was just for presenting my issue. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

@quasoft is correct. Another way to deal with these kinds of `GROUP BY` problems (when you want to return more column than what you want to group by. In your case, you need to return location_id, person_id. But you only need to group by person_id), is to use [analytical functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions).

```
--schema:
CREATE TABLE my_table 
  ( 
     location_id NUMBER, 
     person_id   NUMBER, 
     date_       DATE 
  ); 

INSERT ALL 
INTO my_table 
VALUES (3, 65, To_date('2016-06-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
INTO my_table 
VALUES (7, 23, To_date('2016-10-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
INTO my_table 
VALUES (3, 23, To_date('2016-08-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
INTO my_table 
VALUES (5, 65, To_date('2016-07-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
SELECT * 
FROM   dual; 

--query:
WITH ordered 
     AS (SELECT location_id, 
                person_id, 
                date_, 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY person_id 
                    ORDER BY date_ DESC) RN 
         FROM   my_table) 
SELECT location_id, 
       person_id, 
       date_ 
FROM   ordered 
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

The query `ordered` sort your rows for each group by date. The main query, returns the first 1 of each group after it is sorted. Hence, it will return the in this case the last one (we ordered by date_ desc).

Answer (score 0):

This might work!

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table A
JOIN (SELECT PERSON_ID,MAX(DATE) as MaxDate FROM Your_Table 
GROUP BY PERSON_ID) B
ON A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID AND A.DATE = B.MaxDate
```