# Selecting the most recent entry (row) using datetime column

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table that looks like this:

```
table_name  |  event_time           |  row_count  |  num_of_times_observed
test        |  2016-11-30 15:33:47  |  200        |  0
test        |  2016-11-30 16:03:03  |  400        |  0
test11      |  2016-11-30 15:33:34  |  300        |  0
test11      |  2016-11-30 15:57:49  |  400        |  0
```

I would like to find the row that has the most recent value in `event_time`given a table name (or to be more general, by each distinct table name). For example, if we are to find the most recent time for `table_name`, 'test11', we'd get a result like this:

```
table_name  |  event_time           |  row_count  |  num_of_times_observed
test11      |  2016-11-30 15:57:49  |  400        |  0
```

There are two standard (beginner) approaches that I can think of to achieve that:

```
SELECT table_name -- Approach#1
    ,event_time
    ,row_count
    ,num_of_times_observed
FROM my_table AS u
WHERE table_name = 'test11'
ORDER BY event_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or this:

```
SELECT table_name -- Approach#2
    ,event_time
    ,row_count
    ,num_of_times_observed
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE table_name = 'test11'
    ) AS u -- I really don't need to filter by table_name here, but I hope it will improve the performance by just a little (especially if there are >100K rows for 'test11')?
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT table_name
        ,max(event_time) AS event_time
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY table_name
    HAVING table_name = 'test11'
    ) AS q ON u.table_name = q.table_name
    AND u.event_time = q.event_time
```

Assuming there are ~100 million rows in `my_table`, I feel like the above approaches may not be very efficient (optimized). I looked around StackOverflow for possible answers and found answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435749/1330974) that are more advanced. I wonder if there are better (efficient) way to query for the desired result.

Thank you very much for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you want a list of the most recent event of all tables or only one table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. Tagged with the DB that I use. :)

Comment: @mcNets For one table is enough for my current use case. But I'd love to learn how to do it for ALL tables, too. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is the best approach.

You want an index on `my_table(table_name, event_time)`.  Some databases allow you to specify `desc` on the column when creating the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also

for each table

```
select * from my_table 
where ( table_name, event_time) in ( select table_name, max(event_time) 
                                from my_table
                                    group by table_name )
```

or if you are using a db that not allowd  the use of tuple you can use
a join

```
 select * from my_table t1 
 INNER JOIN (  
   select table_name, max(event_time) max_event 
   from my_table
   group by table_name ) t2 on t2.table_name = t1.table_name 
                                   and t2.max_event = t1.event_time
```

for absolute

```
select * from my_table as  u
where event_time in ( select max(event_time )  from my_table)
```

Comment: The query for each table returns Syntax error. I think `where (table_name, event_time) in (select ...) is not allowed in SQL.

Comment: which db  you are using ?

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer for db that eventually don't use tuple ..

Comment: Thank you! I use Vertica. But seems like the `INNER JOIN` and the standard `ORDER BY` are the way to go.